# FTP software that checks data diffs?

Tags: ftp

I am looking for an FTP program (free if possible) that can find diffs between the client and server so it does not have to upload 50 gb every time I commit files.

I cannot use `svn` since this machine is not on my network.

Comment: If you have root access to the machine, you can simply perform an `svn update`. As you're looking for a FTP solution, I suppose this isn't the case.

Comment: To extend on @Paul a bit: the phrase "every time i commit files" makes us think you might actually need some tools to deploy a specific revision (or just the latest...) on the production machine, rather than copying some local version to that machine? (I'd say something like `svn export` instead of `svn update`, and no root access needed.)

Comment: @Eran, after signing in to Super User, be sure to associate your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/users/205477?tab=accounts -- and don't forget to read the FAQs. Thanks!

Comment: (You could use `svn` if you can connect through SSH, by setting up some tunnel.)

Answer (score 6):

How about using [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)?

Comment: I use gadmin-rsync on Ubuntu.

Comment: the server does not support it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a desktop application, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) is a good choice, but if you want something you can target programmatically, [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) is probably better. In what context are you going to use this?

Answer (score 1):

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) will do the job

Answer (score 0):

[sitecopy](http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/) might be suitable. [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) is designed for this purpose as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) can also be useful for your task -- and it can so much more.

Answer (score 0):

"[Synchronizing files over FTP](https://superuser.com/questions/33856/syncronizing-files-over-ftp)" here at Super User mentions `wput` and `ncftp`/`ncftpput`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility app that did this:  compute SHA256 hash of each file to be uploaded.  Produce a text file with those hashes and the filenames - an index file.  Download the server-based index file.  If it is not present, then assume all files need to be refreshed.  If it is present, then, for each file to be uploaded:

- check the hash in the downloaded text file
- if the hash is not present then upload
- if the hash is present and does not match the hash of the current (local) file, then upload
- if the hash is present and matches, skip the file.

After all file uploads complete, upload the new index file.

Rather than uploading 500 files each time, it now uploads only the changed files, plus the index file.

Comment: ...but how would using such index file find changes made to remote files (or even deletions) by some other process or user?

Comment: obviously it does not.  If someone else changes the file, without updating the index file, then the system is going to fail.

Comment: Let's hope you're not maintaining some power plant then. ;-)