# ftp command line without overwrite?

Tags: linux, mac, command-line, ftp

I transfered 15gb over the network. I have aother 10 to go. How do i transfer via cmd line without overwriting existing files? I want to skip files so i dont store it again. I dont need unique names for this.

Comment: Could be a bit more specific? transfer what?

Comment: See "FTP software that checks data diffs?" at http://superuser.com/questions/68411/ftp-software-that-checks-data-diffs and "Syncronizing files over FTP" at http://superuser.com/questions/33856/syncronizing-files-over-ftp

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `ftp` lists the `sunique` and `runique` FTP subcommands which toggle saving files with unique filenames, as a way of avoiding overwriting existing files:

ie, `file.1` if `file` exists, `file.2` if `file.1` exists, etc.

These are `ftp` commands, not OS command-line options *for* `ftp`, but I think the `.netrc` file could be used to toggle `sunique` or `runique` from the default OFF state when ftp starts.

Comment: I am not worry about overwriting, just writing the same file again when i dont need to (thus the skipping which i forgot to mention!). Can i use sunique to plainly skip a file? I am thinking i should wipe the remote folder and start clean early during the day.

Answer (score 1):

Between two Unix-based systems, why not just [use rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) instead? It was written precisely to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers posted, wget should do anything you require quite easily.

Comment: That's quite an odd (or creative) use of wget. How would one use that?

Comment: would i need a wput ;). The machine on the other send (ftp host) is a windows while this one is a mac.

Comment: Arjan, "wget --no-clobber -c ftp://sunsite.doc.ic.ac.uk/ls-lR.Z" will download all files from the FTP site at sunsite, while not clobbering local files.  Acidzombie, there are wget binaries available for the Mac (install via Fink) and Windows (http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#download).

Comment: Wget for the win!  I'm up-voting this one.