# How to upload one file by FTP from command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I need to upload a single file to FTP server from Ubuntu. This operation should be done in a script (in non-interactive mode). What is the right syntax for `ftp`?

I'm trying this, to no avail:

```
$ ftp -u ftp://user:secret@ftp.example.com my-local-file.txt
ftp: Invalid URL `ftp://'
```

Comment: How do I man page?

Comment: I don't know much about the `ftp` tool in Ubuntu, but it looks like it's choking on the `ftp://`. try taking that out maybe?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `man ftp` at command line

Comment: Similar: [Syncronizing files over FTP](http://superuser.com/q/33856/87805), but for multiple files.

Comment: I'm getting '-u unknown option'.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
$ ftp -n <<EOF
open ftp.example.com
user user secret
put my-local-file.txt
EOF
```

---

Alternatively, create (or edit) the ~/.netrc file in the home dir of the user that will run the ftp command, give it appropriate perms (`chmod 0600 ~/.netrc`), and add the following:

```
# ~/.netrc
machine ftp.example.com
login user
password secret
```

Then omit the login information, as in:

```
$ echo put my-local-file.txt | ftp ftp.example.com
```

---

Also, here's how you might do the same thing using curl:

```
$ curl -T my-local-file.txt ftp://ftp.example.com --user user:secret
```

Comment: FYI: I've noticed that I can't pass a full path of the file using the `put` raw command but I can with `curl`.

Comment: +1 for the curl. Neat, clean and straight to the point! In Debian/Ubuntu "apt-get install curl", if you don't have it.

Comment: the `curl` solution is the best and the easiest

Comment: FWIW: I tried this with a large file (162MB). At first I thought curl looked slow (~25mins), but I found that the ftp command took just as long. curl looks good if available, and has nice feedback showing Time Left etc.

Comment: ftp.example.com:port for connection that require that.

Comment: A variant of this syntax is:

`$ curl -T my-local-file.txt ftp://user:secret@ftp.example.com`

Comment: For those who are going to use `curl` it is important to put your password inside single quotes `'` if it contain special characters. otherwise you will end up with `curl: (67) Access denied: 530`

Comment: For uploads to a specific folder put a slash after the folder name: `ftp://ftp.example.com/myFolder/` otherwise youl'll get "Failed FTP upload: 553"

Comment: Will this leave the password in the bash history? Can I prevent that?

Comment: @Xanlantos yes. You can just leave out the password and you will be prompted for the password by curl.

Comment: The long version of the `-T` parameter, for those not wishing to peruse curl's enormous man page, is `--upload-file` and specifies the local file to upload (nothing more).

Answer (score 25):

I can recommend `ftp-upload`. It's a neat little tool that you can install under ubuntu through `sudo apt-get install ftp-upload`.

Usage example:

```
ftp-upload -h {HOST} -u {USERNAME} --password {PASSWORD} -d {SERVER_DIRECTORY} {FILE_TO_UPLOAD}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tool or its documentation?

Comment: Hi DragonLord, if you are in Ubuntu and you have installed ftp-upload (using the command I gave before) you can just do `man ftp-upload`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Will this leave the password in the bash history? Can I prevent that?

Comment: @Xanlantos yes unfortunately it will leave the password in the bash history. I think there are ways around it I found through Google (but I don't recall exactly).

Answer (score 6):

You need to fix the URL given in your statement. You received the error because the URL was incomplete - it was missing the name of the object you are uploading. Once you add the filename after 'example.com' as I have done below, you will see the single command does indeed work as you intended.

Try this:

`ftp -u ftp://user:secret@ftp.example.com/my-local-file.txt my-local-file.txt`

Comment: ftp: invalid option -- 'u'

Comment: Indeed :( ftp: u: unknown option

Comment: ftp: u: unknown option

Comment: perhaps it's version dependant, like `nc -e` flag. my `ftp` command has the `-u` and following this format, it worked nicely!

Comment: Ah I just figured one thing out: this is because my `ftp` command is, actually, `tnftp`. You may want to check what FTP client you're actually using, since they'll have different capabilities!

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).

Here is an example:

```
lftp -e 'cd folder1/folder2; put /home/path/yourfile.tar; bye' -u user,password ftp.theserver.com
```

Refer here for [more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175671/automate-transfer-of-tar-files-over-ftp) and also refer to [LFTP Manual](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

.

Comment: To use it with non unix name I found this:
`NN="'non unix.file'" ; lftp -e "cd folder; put $NN; bye" -u anonymous, ftp.theserver.com`

Comment: Will this leave the password in the bash history? Can I prevent that?

Comment: With the example above yes, it will be in the history. You can use the `--env-password` flag and have the password configured in `LFTP_PASSWORD` environment variable. Refer to the man pages of [LFTP](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

Answer (score 5):

Install ncftp and use the **ncftpput** tool that comes along with it, pretty much something like this syntax:

```
ncftpput -u ftpuser -p ftppass ftphostname /path/where/to/upload localfile.name
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "Upload failed"; fi
```

You can even check if the upload status is good or bad.
The normal ftp client can also be used along with expect.

Answer (score 2):

I use BusyBox's `ftpput` to do this:

```
# /bin/busybox ftpput

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Debian 1:1.20.0-7) multi-call binary.

Usage: ftpput [OPTIONS] HOST [REMOTE_FILE] LOCAL_FILE

Upload a file to a FTP server

    -v,--verbose            Verbose
    -u,--username USER      Username
    -p,--password PASS      Password
    -P,--port NUM           Port
```

Note: `busybox ftpget` work well too.

Answer (score 2):

Upload a file to a remote location via command line

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is the file name
#usage:this_script <filename>
HOST='yourhost'
USER="youruser"
PASSWD="pass"
FILE="abc.php"
REMOTEPATH='/html'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $REMOTEPATH
put $FILE 
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

i improved Marty answer like below (include binary):

[ftp_example_1.sh]

$ ftp_example_sh.sh dump_file

```
ftp -n <<EOF
open 192.168.0.10
user anonymous aaa
binary
put $1
EOF
```

[ftp_example_2.sh]

$ftp_example_2.sh 192.168.0.10 dump_file

```
ftp -n <<EOF
open $1
user anonymous aaa
binary
put $2
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `put` command after connecting to the FTP server with `ftp` (it is interactive, btw).

```
put local-file [remote-file]
             Store a local file on the remote machine.  If remote-file is left unspecified, the local file name is used after processing according to any ntrans or nmap settings in
             naming the remote file.  File transfer uses the current settings for type, format, mode, and structure.
```

Example login:

```
~ $ ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 25 allowed.
220-Local time is now 10:47. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (127.0.0.1:user1): user2
331 User user2 OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

Example copy (login required before it):

```
ftp> put index.html
local: index.html remote: index.html
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 43791
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.003 seconds (measured here), 3.96 Mbytes per second
10701 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (34.4773 MB/s)
```

Example logout (login required before it)

```
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 11 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

With curl:

```
curl -T $file -u "$user:$pass" ftp://xxxxx.xxx[:$port]/server/path [--ftp-ssl] [-k]
```

Between braces are optionals

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the sftp or ftp command

`sftp {user}@{IP}`
`Password:`
`put {path To File On Local Computer}`

Answer (score -1):

```
FtpPut(){
    echo `echo -e "open host\nuser user pass\nbinary\nput $1\nquit"|ftp -nv`
}
FtpPut asd.txt
FtpPut asd.mp4
FtpPut asd.php
...
```